# How I can obtain u and z?

Tags: equation-solving

Integrate[1/Sqrt(2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u]) , {y, z, u}] == 0.013

2*Cosh[z] - 2*Cosh[u] == 0.41

Can I obtain the parameters of u and z using above equations?

Answer (score 1):

```
Assuming[{y \[Element] Reals, z \[Element] Reals, u \[Element] Reals,
```

u > z}, Integrate[1/Sqrt[Cosh[y] - Cosh[u]]/Sqrt[2], {y, z, u}]]

Gives

```
-I Abs[Csch[u/2]] ((Sqrt[-Cosh[u] + Cosh[z]] EllipticF[(I z)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2])/Sqrt[Cosh[u] - Cosh[z]] + (EllipticF[(I u)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2] Sqrt[Sinh[u]])/Sqrt[-Sinh[u]])
```

simplifying we have

```
equ1 = Abs[Csch[u/2]] (-EllipticF[(I u)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2] + EllipticF[(I z)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2]) == 0.013;

equ2 = 2 Cosh[z] - 2 Cosh[u] == 0.41;
```

and after

```
ContourPlot[{Abs[Csch[u/2]] (-EllipticF[(I u)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2] + EllipticF[(I z)/2, -Csch[u/2]^2]) == 0.013, 2 Cosh[z] - 2 Cosh[u] == 0.41}, {u, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

we obtain

```
FindRoot[{equ1, equ2}, {{u, 4.2}, {z, 4}}]
(*{u -> 4.58887 + 2.0437*10^-6 I, z -> 4.59303 + 2.03521*10^-6 I}*)
FindRoot[{equ1, equ2}, {{u, 4.588870309567742`}, {z, 4.593029454247072`}}]

(*{u -> 4.58887 - 7.54237*10^-20 I, z -> 4.59303 - 7.51106*10^-20 I}*)
```

practically

```
u = 4.588870309567761`
z = 4.593029454247091`
```

Comment: Your integral is wrong, it should be `Integrate[1/Sqrt[2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u]] , {y, z, u}]` and things become much more complicated.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I apologize for the inconvenience caused. I will try to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

`CountourPlot`shows the possible solutions. Try

```
ContourPlot[{NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u]], {y, z, u}] == .013,2 Cosh[z] - 2 Cosh[u] == 0.41}, {z, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5},FrameLabel -> {z, u}]
```

[image]

Obviously the solution fullfills `u \[TildeEqual] z && u, z < 0`

```
NMinimize[{1, {NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2*Cosh[y] - 2*Cosh[u]], {y, z, u}] == .013 &&2 Cosh[z] - 2 Cosh[u] == 0.41}}, {u, z}]
(*{1., {u -> -4.51754, z -> -4.52201}}*)
```